# Unable to install IBM Bluemix Eclipse plugin for Luna and Mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin, ibm-cloud-tools

I am tried to install IBM Bluemix eclipse plugin for **Eclipse Mars** from Eclipse Market place. Eclipse listing all required libraries and dependencies but installation its showing following error as shown in image.

[image: Screenshot of Error]
**Note:**

> I was able to download install other eclipse plugins like PyDev,Subclipse etc.

Any suggestions or links? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Eclipse are you using?  I just tried with the JEE Package for Mars SR1: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars1.  Then, search for the Eclipse marketplace entry from Eclipse and do the install.

and I can complete the install successfully.  It may just be a temporary outage on the server.  Would you mind to try it again?

If the problem still exist, can you list out the details of your setup, e.g. Eclipse package that you start with, platform, steps to reproduce, etc. so I can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

Comment: I assume you have tried the installation again recently to confirm that it is not a temporary outage on the server.  Which platform are you using?  Also, are you using the same step as I listed before or use different steps?  It will be helpful if you can specify the steps that you used if your steps are different.

Comment: **@Elson** : Yes I have tried but still it showing same error. Let me try with Eclipse Luna.  I am using windows 7 OS / 64 bit and I have followed steps described in the Bluemix tutorials provided in the IBM portal. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: If you are still having problem on the install, we have now got the Bluemix EPP package available for download, i.e. a single zip file that contains both Eclipse and Bluemix Tools that you can just unzip and use without extra installation steps. You can find from the EPP Package download from here:
http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/eclipse/